# CSV file in Python row

Tags: python, csv

Why I am getting the space after one row and it is moving onto third row, when I write the code to open a CSV file in excel?

[image]

I have used the code below.

```
import csv

with open("self_taught.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    spamwriter.writerow(["one", "two", "three"])
    spamwriter.writerow(["four", "five", "six"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `newline=""` when open csv by python.

EX:

```
with open(pathToFile, newline='') as f:
 ...
```

Comment: I mean in the excel file, I get second row blank after the first row, and my code moves onto the 3rd row why is that.

Comment: i want somehow ,my second row gets filled.

Comment: Please can anyone help

Comment: `with open("self_taught.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:`

Comment: thank you very much,it really means alot to me.